# I have a function f(w,x,y,z) and a target value A, how can I discover values for w,x,y,z that produce A?

Tags: algorithm, function, numbers

So I have a function that takes four numerical arguments and produces a numerical argument.

```
f(w,x,y,z) --> A
```

If I have the function `f` and a target result `A`, is there an iterative method for discovering parameters `w,x,y,z` that produce a given number `A`?

If it helps, my function `f` is a quintic bezier where most of the parameters are determined. I have isolated just these four that are required to fit the value `A`.

```
Q(t)=R(1−t)^5+5S(1−t)^4*t+10T(1−t)^3*t^2+10U(1−t)^2*t^3+5V(1−t)t^4+Wt^5
```

`R,S,T,U,V,W` are vectors where `R` and `W` are known, I have isolated only a single element in each of `S,T,U,V` that vary as parameters.

Comment: It largely depends on the function itself - in the most general case, you'll have to iterate over every possible tuple of `(w,x,y,z)`

Comment: There's not enough information here. This will depend on what your function F does. You will likely also need to set an upper bound limit. You will probably want to approach this algorithmically, rather than brute-forcing iteratively too.

Comment: Well, the function is a quintic bezier where I have isolated these four elements of the six vectors that are allowed to vary.  I added more information.

Comment: @multiphrenic Right, I am looking for an algorithm.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to tell you anything specific to a quintic bezier, but you might want to look at the standard optimizations functions available in a package like `SciPy`, or just at black-box search algorithms (BBSAs) in general. They solve a superset of your problem, but they should work.

Comment: Your description of your function in terms of a vector-based function still seems confusing / not complete enough  -- can you work out the math and update the post with the actual function in the 4 variables you are trying to fit?  This may lead to much better answers.

Comment: Are the numeric arguments integers, rationals, reals, complex numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of solutions of the equation `f(w,x,y,z)=A` (where all of `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` and `A` are scalars) is, in general, a 3 dimensional manifold (surface) in the 4-dimensional space `R^4` of `(w,x,y,z)`.  I.e., the solution is *massively* non-unique.

Now, if `f` is simple enough for you to compute its derivative, you can use the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find *a* root: the gradient is the direction of the fastest change of the function, so you go there.

Specifically, let `X_0=(w_0,x_0,y_0,z_0)` be your initial approximation of a solution and let `G=f'(X_0)` be the gradient at `X_0`. 
Then `f(X_0+h)=f(X_0)+(G,h)+O(|h|^2)` (where `(a,b)` is the dot product).
Let `h=a*G`, and solve `A=f(X_0)+a*|G|^2` to get `a=(A-f(X_0))/|G|^2` (if `G=0`, change `X_0`) and `X_1=X_0+a*G`. If `f(X_1)` is close enough to `A`, you are done, otherwise proceed to compute `f'(X_1)` &c.

If you cannot compute `f'`, you can play with many other methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use Newton's method to solve a multi-variate system of equations where there are more variables than equations?

Answer (score 2):

If you can impose 3 (or more) additional equations that you know (or suspect) must be true for your 4-variable solution that gives target value `A`, then you can try applying Newton's method for solving a system of k equations with k unknowns.  Otherwise, without a deeper understanding of the structure of the function you are trying to make equal to `A`, the only general type of technique I'm aware of that's easy to implement is to simply define the error function as `g(w,x,y,z) = |f(w,x,y,z) - A|` and search for a minimum of `g`.  Typically the "minimum" found will be a local minimum, so it may require many restarts of the minimization problem with different starting values for your parameters to actually find a solution that gives a local minimum you want of `g = 0`.  This is very easy to implement and try in a few lines e.g. in MATLAB using `fminsearch`